# IO operations with Sockets

Tags: c#, multithreading, sockets, io

I want to receive constantly while a socket is alive and call concurrently to a send method from different threads (I'm sorry for my English).

I have thought about the following:

- As there will be multiple clients I think it would be better if the operating system is responsible for generating the threads so as not to compromise the performance, therefore, I do not want to check the Receive method in a loop on a different thread for each client. This I discarded instantly.
- To avoid the creation of instances of the type that implements the IAsyncResult interface used in each call to BeginReceive and thus not stress the GB and have a better performance when there is a heavy load of IO operations I decided not to use BeginReceive / EndReceive.
- Instead, I've thought about using the ReceiveAsync method and a reusable SocketAsyncEventArgs instance for each connection. For example, if the server supports 1000 connections, it will have that same number of instances of SocketAsyncEventArgs, one for each client during the time the connection is alive. When the client disconnects the underlying SocketAsyncEventArgs instance will return to the pool for later use in another connection (SOLUTION CHOSEN)
- Regarding the sending operation, I do not care that the send requests are not processed in the order of call; the important thing is that the bytes do not mix with those of other messages, so that in the buffer of reception in the remote host the messages arrive one after the other so that the class that is in charge of the protocol can interpret them.
- For this, I do not want to call BeginSend / EndSend because apart from creating different IAsynResult instances in each call, I understand that there is a possibility that message bytes are mixed when calling from different threads, is that correct? I do not remember where I read it a long time ago. I would like to have reliable sources. Regardless of whether it is true or not, I do not intend to use it.
- I also understand that SendAsync is like a mask for BeginSend / EndSend, with the difference that it reuses the underlying IAsyncResult instance. Which makes me think that although I can concurrently call the SendAsyn method as well as BeginSend, there is also the possibility that the bytes are mixed in the output buffer.
- To process multiple calls with SendAsyn you should also provide a different instance of SocketAsyncEventArgs on each call, which I do not like. Then I thought about using the Semaphore class to guarantee a sending operation at a time and once completed, reuse the SocketAsyncEventArgs instance used in the previous send operation. This way I would only occupy two instances of SocketAsyncEventArgs per connection (one to receive and one to send) and I avoided having a pool of these objects and not only that, it would also prevent the bytes of different messages from being mixed in the output buffer.
- Regarding the solution that I found to receive constantly I am satisfied. But for the shipping operation I'm not sure. I do not find any advantage when using SendAsync. I only want multiple threads can call concurrently to the shipping method. Then I thought about using the Send method and wrapping it in an asynchronous method like the one shown below:

  ```
  public virtual async Task<int> SendAsync(byte[] buffer, int offset, int size, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
  {
      ThrowIfDisposed();

      var sendingRequest = CancellationTokenSource.CreateLinkedTokenSource(requests.Token, cancellationToken);

      int bytesSent = 0;

      try
      {
          await semaphore.WaitAsync(sendingRequest.Token).ConfigureAwait();

          while(bytesSent < size)
          {
              int bytesWrote = clientSocket.Send(buffer, offset, size, SocketFlags.None);

              if(bytesWrote == 0)
              {
                  throw new SocketException((int)SocketError.NotConnected);
              }
              else
              {
                  bytesSend += bytesWrote;
              }
          }
       }
       catch(SocketException)
       {
           Disconnect();

           throw;
       }
       finally
       {
           semaphore.Release();

           sendingRequest.Dispose();
           sendingRequest = null;
       }

       return bytesSent;
  }
  ```

I would appreciate it if you would tell me in which parts of everything I said above I am wrong or if my approach is correct or how to improve what I already have.

Thanks.

Comment: TL;DR - please provide a description of what you're wanting to do in terms of your business requirement, not the specific technology you're choosing. Then we can help.

Comment: @Enigmativity Hi. I often do network applications. I want to save resources by making a library to simplify things. In the design, I have a class called TcpConnection from which a new instance will be created for each connection received. This class must provide IO mechanisms; that is, a DataReceived event every time data is received and an asynchronous SendAsync method that can be called simultaneously from different threads.

Comment: @Enigmativity ...As I said in the description, so far I have thought about using ReceiveAsync and SocketAsyncEventArgs for the receiving and the SendAsync method attached for the sending. I would like to know if there is something wrong like my approach.

Comment: "not the specific technology you're choosing"

Comment: @Enigmativity. I thought that I had said that this is C # NET Standard 2.0

Comment: You keep missing my point. Please describe what you want to do **without** specifying the technology that you want to use. I want to understand the general requirements.